# How to delete data from Mongodb and table row at a same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my first question on StackOverflow. When following RESTful routes, you can make a delete button that destroys a single page and entry in MongoDB.

My question is how to make a delete button that destroys only a single table row and the same data from MongoDB? I can add a contact successfully, but I don't know how to delete it from a page

This is my code for a table that needs modification:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Telephone Number</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
   <% phonebook.forEach(function(contact){ %>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <%= contact.firstName %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= contact.lastName %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= contact.phone %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <form action="/phonebook?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <% }); %>
  </table>
```

And this is my code from routes, that needs modification:

```
//DESTROY 
app.delete("/phonebook/:id", function(req, res){
    Phonebook.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
      if(err){
        res.redirect("/phonebook");
      } else {
                res.redirect("/phonebook");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: How about replacing `<form action="/phonebook?_method=DELETE" method="POST">` with `<form action="/phonebook/<%= contact.id %>" method="DELETE">`?

Comment: This is what I get with your answer when I click on delete:

Cannot GET /phonebook/5b69ad02acea7f042ede3a41

Comment: Ups, my bad. I forgot that html form can't send DELETE. Try this: `<form action="/phonebook/<%= contact.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">`

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Great. I moved it to answer so others can easily understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<form action="/phonebook?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
```

To:

```
<form action="/phonebook/<%= contact.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
```